# How to use pipe in Flask/Jinja template differently than filters?

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2, peewee

I'm using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) with the [Jinja2 templating engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org) to build a website. As an ORM I use the (excellent) [Peewee ORM](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) and I now run into a problem.

In my Flask view I get a list of users from the DB:

```
@app.route('/stats')
def stats():
    users = User.select()
    return render_template('stats.html', users=users)
```

and in my template I loop over the users and try to expand the query. This works:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.app_logs.where(AppLog.type == 'LOGIN').first().created }}
{% endfor %}
```

but this:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.app_logs.where((AppLog.type == 'LOGIN') | (AppLog.type == AppLog.TICKET)).first().created }}
{% endfor %}
```

gives a `TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got '('`. I understand what the error comes from: the pipe symbol (`|`) is defined as [a filter in Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#filters). So I tried escaping it with a backslash (`\|`) but that doesn't work.

So my question: is there a way to somehow escape the pipe symbol or does anybody have any other idea to make this work? All tips are welcome!

Comment: I don't know Peewee, but looks like it has an `<<` operator that translates to `IN`, so wouldn't `user.app_logs.where(AppLog.type << ['LOGIN', AppLog.TICKET])` work?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Next to it being a better query, that was quite a good idea. But unfortunately that doesn't work either: `TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '<'`. Thanks for the tip of using `IN` for this query though!

Comment: Write a method on your `User` model and call this method from your template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case, it's a better practice to keep the template 'dumb' and to conduct your queries outside of the template. In your case you can use the [playhouse extension to use hybrid attributes on the model](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/3cb2d9b594ad794c90a3182726ef4a8477a95a41/docs/peewee/playhouse.rst).

```
class User(Model):
    ...

    @hybrid_property
    def applog_login_ticket(self):
        return self.app_logs.where((AppLog.type == 'LOGIN') | (AppLog.type == AppLog.TICKET)).first().created()
```

And then in your template you can just do

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.applog_login_ticket }}
{% endfor %}
```